# How to integrate OpenIdconnect with istio?

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak, istio, jwt

I want to authenticate end users using **JWT** provided by OpenId connect providers like keycloak or auth0..etc in a **istio** service mesh.But I am not able to successfully integrate it proboably because I am new to JWT auth and istio.

Can someone provide right information and sources to complete the authentication?It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some links which could be helpful with [JWT](https://jwt.io/)

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/istio-samples/tree/master/security-intro#add-end-user-jwt-authentication
- https://istiobyexample.dev/jwt/
- https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication

---

For JWT with [auth0](https://auth0.com/)

- https://itnext.io/securing-kubernetes-withistio-end-user-authentication-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-97f4bb8e71c6
- https://auth0.com/blog/securing-kubernetes-clusters-with-istio-and-auth0/

---

And for JWT with [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)

- https://www.dangtrinh.com/2019/08/end-user-authentication-with-istio-and.html

---

> But I am not able to successfully integrate it proboably because I am new to JWT auth and istio.

If you have tried 1 of below tutorials and it didn't work my suggestion would be to create new stackoverflow question and accurately describe your problem there, so community could actually help you with your issue.

---

I hope those links help you. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks..I am able to get the access tokens and verify it in istio using postman.But how will I  get the user login page from keycloak?Do I have to write any code in my application or any frontend code?

Comment: Hey @sachin, what you mean by "get the user login page"? You want to access your keycloak site like in the `4. Set up the client on KeyCloak` from the keycloak tutorial?

Comment: I completed upto step 10.I also get the access tokens in the next step. But the next step 11 testing confuses me.How do  a normal user login flow with authentication occur? By user login, I meant user giving his user name and password to keycloak and then keycloak verifies the credentials.

Comment: I think that line in step 11 explain everything? 'Because I don't implement any application to handle the user authentication flow so to test the scenario, I just use get the access token by calling the KeyCloak token endpoint using HTTP client'. If you want to have login page then based on [this tutorial](https://scalac.io/user-authentication-keycloak-1/) you need some frontend code for that.

Comment: thank you very much ..i was having doubt on how to redirect the user to login page and now I understand.

Comment: @sachin Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.